# SQL Server Object Explorer doesn't display current databases

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, visual-studio

Currently all my SQL Server Object Explorer shows is the following:

[image]

But I cannot get it to display my existing databases as shown in the image below (not from my PC):

[image]

I've never had this issue before. How can I display these databases in the SQL Server Object Explorer?

Comment: It is a different instance of SQL in each of the images. Are there definitely databases on `(localdb)\projects`? Do you have permission on all of these databases?

Comment: The answer you need is problably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200162/ssdt-on-visual-studio-2012-broken-then-fixed-broken-again-also-broken-on-vs2013).

Answer (score 2):

In the second image from another source, you have 2 server connections.  In your computer, you only have localdb projects.  Right click the Servers and select Add Server from the context menu.  Then add your local instance.