# SQL Server Object Explorer doesn't show my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I started a MVC project on VS2012, created my models, my controllers and my views. I'm using Entity Framework code-first, so I've enabled migrations and I'm updating the database accordingly to the changes in the code.
The pages run just fine, the database is working properly, the data is being retrieved as it should, so functionally, everything is fine.

The problem is that I see no connection string in my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Nor do the database shows up in the SQL Server Object Explorer...
I've already checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200162/ssdt-on-visual-studio-2012-broken-then-fixed-broken-again-also-broken-on-vs2013), but the server on my Object Explorer was already the correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are connected using Default Connection Factory, it allows the program to locate the database ONLY when there are no connection strings specified in the config file.

As in your web.config, I've found

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```

Your program may be using this default connection to connect the database.

The Default Connection may have been set up when you installed the EF Nuget Package.

For more about Default Connection Factory, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj556606.aspx#Factory