# SQL Server Object Explorer in VS2015 Professional not showing Azure database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

Microsoft at it again. So my SQL object explorer in Visual Studio stopped working and shows the error in yellow. The mentioned element is a symmetric key that I generated in order to use AES encryption. Now having it is useless for me because I have to open SSMS if I want to checkout a table structure. Any ideas on how to get this solved?

[image: Error show in yellow]

**EDIT**

Please stop answers specifying to update Azure SDK, it's not related and has not worked

Comment: you can get back to V12 compatibility OR change the encryption.|
quoting MS:"Beginning with SQL Server 2016, all algorithms other than AES_128, AES_192, and AES_256 are deprecated. To use older algorithms (not recommended) you must set the database to database compatibility level 120 or lower."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188357.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment @sqlandmore.com, it's fuuny though, because the key is an AES 256 key. Also, none of the admins touched the DB nor the DB engine, the project is pretty new and I'm almost positive the version has not changed by anyone. Could you please explain where can we find this further?

Comment: I see you are using V13 - have you tried to run it with compatibility to V12?

Comment: No I have not. This DB is copied from another one my team did not develop. We just use that DB and don't touch any configuration. Not sure if it's V13, the one above is a local server and that's not the one we use, but one on Azure Cloud. I wouldnt know where or what to change

Comment: Did you fix this? I have this issue constantly on certain PCs

Comment: @rolls I fixed it by stop using Visual Studio. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use that latest Visual Studio 2019 Community edition, which contains the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools with SQL Server Object Explorer

Answer (score -3):

I ran into the same problem. I decided to upgrade to the latest as of now Azure SDK 2.7. This fixed my server explorer panel and also added in a new panel called Cloud Explorer. This will hopefully get you going. Here is the link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/20/announcing-the-azure-sdk-2-7-for-net/

Comment: Take out your answer please

Comment: What is the error message in which is marker in yellow. I was not able to see the screen shot that was attached. I am in office maybe network blockage. Please do let me know the message.

Comment: Says: "The element [key_name] is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12"

Comment: In the mean while you can test the connection by going to the Tool> connect to server and please give the Correct Server Name and Select the Database and Test your connection. After pressing ok you should see the Tables in the Data Connection Expanded tab.

Comment: Dude. Come on. Connection is OK, I can query and do everything. The problem is that the DB contents are not displayed as it used to. That's it.

Comment: I might be wrong since no content can be seen for the given DataBase . When you add a connection to the SQL object explorer you are retrieving the MDF file . So whatever DataBase you are connected to the files in that database is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Server. 
To resolve this issue,You must upgrade the database file by creating a new data connection, 
or you must modify the existing connection to this database file. Hope it works.

Comment: I dropped the existing connection and created a new one and nope, doesn't help. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I know you rated me negatively , anyway i was just trying to help you. I think this is the link that will help you resolve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200162/ssdt-on-visual-studio-2012-broken-then-fixed-broken-again-also-broken-on-vs2013

Comment: I also think you are confused as to the question. The problematic DB is on Azure cloud, not on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me. Best of luck.